# numerical integration methods for a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{v}{L}\sin(y +\frac{v}{L}\ln[\cos(Kt+a)] - b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> I need to find a definite integral of an equation.
> $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{v}{L}\sin(y +\frac{v}{L}\ln[\cos(Kt+a)] - b)$$
> where $v, L, K, a, b$ are constants, and '$y$' is a function of '$t$'.

I couldn't integrate into an indefinite form, so I'd like to use some numerical integration methods to approximate it. What methods are suitable for this kind of problems, and I'm little new to this numerical integration and I'd like to improve my knowledge in this, can you suggest me few methods/algorithms not only pertaining to this problem but also commonly used to solve various types of integral equations. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks :)

Comment: Euler's method should be your starting point, then maybe implicit Euler and Heun's method. It's probably best to start with a simpler differential equation too, so you can be sure you're getting the right results from your code. Once you have those you can look at Runge-Kutta methods (most programming languages have these implemented for you, learning to use them will be very useful).

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for the suggestion, I guess those are enough to solve many problems on differential equations in engineering, although I'm just curious to know what other advanced methods are available to solve the differential equations. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Once you know those basic methods you can start looking into adaptive time stepping, stiff solvers, multistep methods, symplectic methods. It's a huge field and there are lots of techniques.

Comment: An outstanding textbook used at the end of undergraduate study or first year of graduate school is: [Finite Difference Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations](https://www.amazon.com/Difference-Methods-Ordinary-Differential-Equations/dp/0898716292). This is the best book that I know of for beginners. There are other books and resources if you are interested in learning about the finite element method.